# cropbox image overlay over-riding drag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery cropbox [Cropbox](http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/) which allows you to drag an image into position before cropping it to size.

What I want to do is enhance the controls to overlay the entire image with a frame to guide the user to the centre.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak6d5/43/

All I have done is amend the cropcontrols class:

```
.cropControls {
background: url("http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y27/Alpha9548/frame_zps0a9f730c.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
height: 100%;
```

}

The problem is that the overlay makes it impossible to drag the image beneath it. Can anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `pointer-events:none;`

And here is a good overview: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/